# Obtener QImage / QPixmap a partir de un Canvas en QML

Tags: c++, qt, canvas, qml

Tengo una view en qml donde se puede dibujar usando un canvas. Una vez se ha dibujado algo en este canvas, quiero obtener la QImage o QPixmap correspondiente para tratarla en C++. 
Como puedo extraer esta imagen?

He intentado hacerlo a través del context, pero todo lo que puedo obtener es un CanvasImageData

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var canvasImageData= ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height)
miMetodo(canvasImageData)
```

miMetodo de C++ espera un QPixmap, pero al ejecutar el código me da el siguiente error:

```
"Could not convert argument 0 at"
         "onClicked@qrc:/views/AcceptFlight/AcceptFlightDetailView.qml:224"
"Passing incompatible arguments to C++ functions from JavaScript is dangerous and deprecated."
"This will throw a JavaScript TypeError in future releases of Qt!"
```